# Error in ternary operator, thowing error: "expected primary-expression before ';' token "

Tags: c++, nested, conditional-operator

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

struct menuItemType {
    string mennuItem;
    double menuPrice;
};

int main() {
    int choice, flag[8]={0}, iNum;
    cout << "Our menu includes:" << endl << "1. Plain Egg $1.45" << endl << "2.Bacon and Egg $2.45" << endl << "3. Muffin $0.99" << endl << "4. French Toast $1.99" << endl <<"5. Fruit Basket $2.49" << endl << "6. Cereal $0.69" << endl <<"7. Coffee $0.50" << endl <<"8. Tea $0.75" << endl;
    menuItemType menuList[8]={{"Plain Egg",1.45},{"Bacon and Egg",2.45},{"Muffin",0.99},{"French Toast",1.99},{"Fruit Basket",2.49}, {"Cereal",1.99},{"Coffee",0.50},{"Tea",0.45}};
    cout << "how many items you wish to order?";
    cin >> choice;
    for (int i=0;i<choice;i++) {
        cout << "enter item number" << i;
        cin >> iNum;
        iNum==1?flag[0]++:iNum==2?flag[1]++:iNum==3?flag[2]++:iNum==4?flag[3]++:iNum==5?flag[4]++:iNum==6?flag[5]++:iNum==7?flag[6]++:iNum==8?flag[7]++:; 
    }
    
    
    return 0;
}
```

I don't understand why it is throwing an error on `iNum==1?flag[0]++:iNum==2?flag[1]++:iNum==3?flag[2]++:iNum==4?flag[3]++:iNum==5?flag[4]++:iNum==6?flag[5]++:iNum==7?flag[6]++:iNum==8?flag[7]++:;`.
The error is  **expected primary-expression before ';' token**, if i remove the last semicolon it throws another error  **expected ':' before ';' token**.

Comment: Please don't write code like `iNum==1?flag[0]++:iNum==2?flag[1]++:iNum==3?flag[2]++:iNum==4?flag[3]++:iNum==5?flag[4]++:iNum==6?flag[5]++:iNum==7?flag[6]++:iNum==8?flag[7]++:;`.  Instead, use if statements.  You'll get the same performance and the code will be much more readable.

Comment: That kind of code will be difficult to debug, as you've just faced. Use if-else statements which is more practical.

Comment: @NathanOliver ok but can you please expleain the error?, and im using this operator to shorten code not for performance :)

Comment: Why do you want to shorten the code?  The length of it ha no practical implication on a desktop computer.  As you can see from having to ask this question, shortened code is often difficult to understand. The reason I can't explain the error is I'm not going to pull my hair out trying to parse the nest of conditional operators.

Comment: It's not true that fewer the characters there are, the faster the code. It'll probably take me only a few dozen characters, or so, to write some code that will continue to execute until our sun explodes, and a few thousand lines of code that will finish much sooner.

Comment: `:;` is invalid. But why the deuce wouldn't you use `++flag[iNum - 1]` having first checked the validity of `iNum`?

Comment: there are cases where you cannot use `if` but you can use the ternary (eg initialization of a reference) and cases where an `if` would be compilcated but a ternary is more readable. Thats the use cases for the ternary, not to replace any `if` and save some keystrokes

Comment: @ShayanHasanKhan `if (iNum >= 1 && iNum <= 8) ++flag[iNum-1];` -- What looks clearer to you?  Your original code, or this?

Answer (score 1):

It ends with `... ? flag[7]++ : ;`
If the last condition (before `?`) is false, you need to provide an expression (after `:`).

That's because `a = b ? c : d;` needs to provide a value for `a`: it could be either `c` or `d`, depending on `b`.

In your case, if the condition is false, what value will you provide?

Answer (score 1):

your condition is incomplete:

```
iNum==1?flag[0]++:iNum==2?flag[1]++:iNum==3?flag[2]++:iNum==4?flag[3]++:iNum==5?
    flag[4]++:iNum==6?flag[5]++:iNum==7?flag[6]++:iNum==8?flag[7]++:;
                                                                   ^
                                                                   |-here
```

so you should add what is the value if `iNum` is not 8

```
iNum==8?flag[7]++:0;
```

Comment: Ohh ok ok got it, rookie mistake sorry and thanks :))

Answer (score 0):

As you wrote, you are using a [ternary operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation). "[Ternary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ternary)" means "made up of three things", and in this case the things are operands. By definition, a ternary operator has three operands.

*(Note: "ternary" describes operators at the same level as "binary". C++ has several binary operators – such as addition – but only one ternary operator, namely the [conditional operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Conditional_operator). Sometimes this leads people to use "ternary" and "conditional" interchangeably. This, in turn, leads some people to use the term "ternary" without realizing what it means.)*

Let's look at the use of the ternary operator that produces your error. *By [simplifying your code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), it is easier to focus on the specific issue.*

```
iNum==8?flag[7]++:;
```

The first operand is `iNum==8`, the second is `flag[7]++`, and the third is... umm... huh? I was expecting to find the third operand before the semicolon (a.k.a. the ';' token). Each operand must be an expression of some sort, which in turn requires at least the presence of a [primary expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/expressions#Primary_expressions), and yet there is no primary-expression after the colon and before the ';' token. One might say that a primary-expression is expected before the ';' token. In fact, I think your compiler did say that... ;)